# What causes the CPU load to less than 100% for parallel code?

Tags: parallel-processing, cpu, mutex, multicore, ram

If the code is parallelized for a multi-core CPU to load this CPU to less than 100%, is it only because of the expectations of I/O and mutexes? Or perhaps because of cache misses and waiting for access to RAM, or something else?

Comment: Without the code and intimate knowledge of the run time environment how do you expect anyone to give you any kind of accurate answer?

Comment: Amen to that. You can parallelise code and have it run no faster than a sequential version. Even if you do it well getting 100% utilization still depends on the problem. This is a poorly asked question. Try providing more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Your process will not be the only process running. Other processes, including the OS kernel will consume a coupe of percentages. Context switching, waiting for I/O and mutexes are only part of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are lots and lots of possible reasons for not achieving 100% CPU usage, we will be unable to determine the exact reasons without more knowledge of your environment.

If your CPU is hyper-threaded (HT) there are more considerations than some other CPU designs; Some parts of the CPU are duplicated, meaning the OS sees your physical cores as multiple logical cores, these logical cores are what the likes of Task Manager display. In certain situations, the non-duplicated parts of the CPU may become the bottleneck, this can mean the duplicated components are unable to run at 100% usage.

Interestingly enough, HT CPUs are states by Intel to only have around a 30% performance increase compared to a non-HT CPU, even though the number of logical cores is doubled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand the gist of your question so I will assume that you are asking why your multi-threaded application does not use 100% of the CPU power available on the core(s).

I experienced something similar when writing a multi-threaded shell sort which used 50% of the capacity available (two cores at 50%) even when there was little else happening i e I was expecting it to use 100% on both cores.

I rectified the problem by using affinity functions to tie the threads to specific cores. On a two-core machine there would only be two threads created. The sort can now use any number of cores (though it doesn't scale beyond three cores) and run all of them at 100%. The work done by the OS and related processes is miniscule compared to the work done by sorting. Since the threads are tied to the cores the OS has little choice/little to do when administering them.

Answer (score 0):

Amdahl's law and synchronization overheads would be my first suspect.  Happens all the time, as long as you have some kind of synchronization or thread management.

If we assume this is close to zero, all the other things brought up in this thread could be it. IO, caches, OS interference, hardware issues like HT (if on Intel x86), ...

One good way to test this is to move the program around to run on different types of architectures (Intel, AMD, Power, Sparc, HT, non-HT) and operating systems, and see if the behavior changes. That tends to reveal to core behavior of the program in a very efficient way.